# Uniqueness of symbols in object methods

Tags: ruby, unique, symbols

Given that symbols are unique, how is it possible that the two instances of`:test` below, which refer to different methods (in different classes), have the same object ID?

```
class Dope
  def test 
  end
end

class Green
  def test
  end
end 

green = Green.new
dope = Dope.new 

green.methods.include?(:test) # => true 
dope.methods.include?(:test) # => true 

green.test.object_id # => 8
dope.test.object_id  # => 8
```

How can you have two symbols with the same name/object ID that refer to different methods?

Comment: It's not about symbols but return values of method calls. The symbol `:test` is just an interface detail of the introspection/reflection API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of your `test` methods return `nil`. So the object id that you get is the object id of `nil`:

```
nil.object_id
# => 8
```

Answer (score 1):

A symbol is stored differently than a string. Any existence of `:test` is always going to equal `:test` because symbols are immutable, unlike strings. There are more descriptions out there [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/24460/what-is-a-symbol-in-ruby) or [here](http://www.reactive.io/tips/2009/01/11/the-difference-between-ruby-symbols-and-strings/).

The `:test` used to determine the presence of that method will be the same symbol `:test` that you store in a different class for `params[:test] = "something`.

Another thing to note that when you call a method on a ruby object, you are technically sending a message to that class. So you're example shows that they both respond to the message `:test`. Which will call the method on the class. This is accurate.

Comment: I have a tendency to ask poorly worded questions (rooted in unclear thinking), but thanks. It still helped.